# Order products from by another table's order

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sold_car 
 WHERE cat_id IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM category 
                ORDER BY cat_id DESC)
```

But result is shown in randomly ordered categories. Why is it not ordered by nested query? Is it a property of Postgresql 9.6?

Comment: Side note: `ORDER BY cat_id DESC` is redundant

Comment: Does the category table only have one column?

Comment: Your query is saying "Return all records from `sold_car` for all records where that record's `cat_id` is somewhere/anywhere in the entire list of `cat_id` from the `category` table." I suspect that is not at all what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way to do what you want:

```
SELECT sc.* 
  FROM sold_car sc 
        INNER JOIN category c 
           ON sc.cat_id = c.cat_id
ORDER BY c.cat_id DESC
```

Your currently query is not ordering or filtering as @jarlh asked "does the category table have only one column?" that's because to use `IN` you should match the columns so it should be `cat_id in (select cat_id from.....`

Also a subquery ordering has no influence on the outer query ordering, so you should ORDER your outer query.

Comment: How can I calculate query time? Because I will make 5-6 INNER JOINs together. Is it a high load query?

Comment: It depends on the amount of data you have in your tables and also the indexes on it. You should run an execution plan on your final query and if it is bad or you don't know how to analyze it you can create another question here.

Comment: you can use [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-explain.html) to work out the affect of your sql

Comment: Thank you, i added "explain" @fcbsd

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select *
from sold_car
where cat_id in
    (select cat_id from catagory) 
order by cat_id desc;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This will not produce the desired results since the OP clearly wants the results DESC ordered by the cat_id. Also makes no sense to use an IN statement with a subquery with a distinct cat_id (as it is presumably the primary key)

Comment: @JorgeCampos you are right, not desired order achieved by this query.